# How to extract multiple files from 7zip compressed file using pylzma

Tags: python, 7zip, compression

i have a 7zip compressed file with .bup extension, after extracting this file using 7zip utility it creates a folder which contains two files....i would like to do the same thing with PyLZMA, can all the files be extracted into a folder using PyLZMA (decompression)?,  could you let me know how can that be done?, i new to this so any detailed help will be really helpful.

Comment: .bup files are just backups of DVD .ifo files, so you don't need a compression library to read them. Instead you could probably adapt Python software that reads the latter to read them, such as the open source [dvdread](http://nullege.com/codes/search/dvdread).

Answer (score 0):

The Python 3.3 module has lzma support built in and comes with [examples](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/lzma#examples)